# How are url scheme and file types handlers found/registered on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am creating a plug-in in Objective-C to a third-party macOS app. I want to register and handle url scheme (like `myscheme://somedatahere`) and file types - for example, when a user double click on a file our plug-in should be notified.

As my product is just a plug-in to a third-party app, the code has no access to the app's NSApplication instance nor to its events. As such, I need to create a helper app and bundle it inside the plug-in bundle/package to register and handle that. Please let me know if these presumptions are incorrect.

The plug-in bundle is being installed inside the `Library/Application Support` (the user typically downloads the plug-in into the Downloads folder, double click it and then the host app's handler copies the plug-in into the Application Support folder). The app handling urls and file types will be placed inside the plug-in bundle. The location was chosen by the host app.

I have several uncertainties I failed to find answers for:

- How does the macOS finds apps capable of handling a particular url scheme and file types?
- Does macOS finds it somewhat automatically or should I call something?
- If it is found automatically, will it work even if the app is located inside a plug-in package outside of the `Applications` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answers you are looking for the in the [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD) documentation.

If you check the section "Application Registration", you will see that:

> A built-in background tool, run whenever the system is booted or a new user logs in, automatically searches the Applications folders in the system, network, local, and user domains and registers any new applications it finds there.
>
> The Finder automatically registers all applications as it becomes aware of them, such as when they are dragged onto the user’s disk or when the user navigates to a folder containing them.

So, if your helper app is installed into /Library/Application Support by the user manually dragging-and-dropping, it looks like Launch Services will see it and register the URL scheme.

Otherwise, the documentation continues to cover the manual case:

> In spite of these automatic registration utilities, it may sometimes be necessary to register an application explicitly with Launch Services. For example, although developers are encouraged to package their applications so that they can be installed by simply dragging them onto the user’s disk, some applications may require more elaborate custom installer software. In such cases, the installer should call one of the Launch Services registration functions LSRegisterFSRef or LSRegisterURL to register the application explicitly.

Comment: My understanding is that the background tool searches just the "virtual" Applications folder. So the helper app would not be discovered by the background tool.

Comment: The plug-in package is usually downloaded by the user to the Downloads folder and then double clicked. The host app then copy the package to the /Library/Application Support folder (so not the user).

Comment: > My understanding is that the background tool searches just the "virtual" Applications folder. So the helper app would not be discovered by the background tool. *Correct*

Comment: > The plug-in package is usually downloaded by the user to the Downloads folder and then double clicked. The host app then copy the package to the /Library/Application Support folder (so not the user). *Then it sounds like you will have to register with Launch Services manually* [LSRegisterURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1446350-lsregisterurl?language=objc)

Comment: My experience with this is that the background tool will still discover them, and will search in many places you don't expect. This is sometimes frustrating, because it can discover your development copies in your home directory and launch the wrong copy of the tool.

Comment: I understand the background tool as the last resort as it would require the user to log off or reboot the computer to finish the plug-in installation. The user will not be able to install the plug-in and immediately double click on a compatible file or click on a compatible URL link.

Comment: Manually calling LSRegisterURL requires that the plug-in code is called during the installation made by the host app (its not) or that we create a script to install the plug-in (not really convenient and comes with its own issues). So if everything is as we discussed here, I need to either convince the host app author to add some APIs or come up with a completely different approach.